# institutionalize

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***institutionalize*** mean in this context? I have looked up in the dictionary but I think the speaker uses metaphor here.

> If you’re in your head, you’re behind enemy lines. That is not God
>   talking, okay? It’s not. In fact, if I put a speaker on it and we
>   broadcast what you say to yourself, we would ***institutionalize***
>   you. You would not hang out with people that talk to you the way you
>   talk to yourself. So get out of your head. Your feelings! Your
>   feelings are screwing you! I don’t care how you feel. I care about
>   what you want.

Source : https://www.ted.com/talks/mel_robbins_how_to_stop_screwing_yourself_over/transcript
*(Please copy some words and Ctrl+F in the transcript, thank you!)*

Comment: Confine to a hospital for the mentally ill.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the speaker uses metaphor here.

He is using metaphor in that paragraph.

Specifically the word *institutionalize* is meant (in a certain sense) literally, but then also as an exaggeration.

By "we would institutionalize you" he means "we would think you were crazy".

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/institutionalize?s=t)

> institutionalize
>   verb (used with object), in·sti·tu·tion·al·ized, > in·sti·tu·tion·al·iz·ing.
>
> 1.
>   2.
>   3. to place or confine in an institution, especially one for the care of mental illness, alcoholism, etc.

[wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/institutionalize)

> Verb
>   institutionalize (third-person singular simple present institutionalizes, present participle institutionalizing, simple past and past participle institutionalized)
>
> 1.
>   2. to commit a person to confinement in an institution

---